# How can I group data by month, day and hour in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have a mysql database that looks like this:

```
id |  userid | timestamp | activity
```

Timestamp is a datetime data type, I need to get the data grouped by month, day and hour. I am using mysql and php for my scripts.

I am able to do it by month and day with the following query:

```
$query = "SELECT COUNT(id) as totals FROM security_transactions WHERE YEAR(timestamp) = 2012 GROUP BY MONTH(timestamp), DAY(timestamp)";
```

I need to do it by month day and hours.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can add `, HOUR(TIME(timestamp))` to your group by query providing your column is of DATETIME format

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_hour

Also, from the error messages put in the comments below, it looks like @Aprentice is not using mysql, but I've improved this answer for others looking for mysql.

I have never used mssql, so I can't test this but the following might work to group by nearest hour:

```
GROUP BY dateadd(hour, datediff(hour, 0, timestamp, 0)
```

Comment: I dont know how this is setup at work but when i use the HOUR() function i get an error, like the function does not exist.

Comment: this is the error i get when i use the hour()function:                                                           Warning: odbc_exec() [function.odbc-exec]: SQL error: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]'hour' is not a recognized function name., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in D:\SecurityServices\temp\moises\Vail_Stats\index.php on line 8

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL and not Microsoft SQL Server?